# How to run dockbarx under unity and GNOME-Shell?

Tags: 11.10, unity, gnome, dockbarx

I have installed [dockbarx](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php?content=101604&forumpage=61) manually from gnome-look, but I can't start it when I search for it in the dash; I only see `dockbarx preference`. So how do I run it and autostart(add to startup) it when Ubuntu starts, and how to run it under GNOME Shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run DockBarX as a stand-alone dock, press ALT + F2 and type:

```
dockx
```

To add it to startup, add the same command to your startup applications list.